# What does this mean: if( variable ){ /* do something */ }

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My question is as title says;

What does this mean:

```
if( variable ){ /* do something */  }
```

I mean if variable exist do something or what?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means if `variable` is *truthy*, then execute the block. In JavaScript, the following are *falsey*

- `false`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `""` (Empty String)

Other than the above, everything else is *truthy*, that is, they evaluate to `true`.

If the variable didn't exist **at all** (that is, it had never been declared), that could would throw a `ReferenceError` because it's trying to read the value of a variable that doesn't exist.

So this would throw an error:

```
if (variableThatDoesntExist) {
    console.log("truthy");
}
```

This would log the word "truthy":

```
var variable = "Hi there";
if (variable) {
    console.log("truthy");
}
```

And this wouldn't log anything:

```
var variable = "";
if (variable) {
    console.log("truthy");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's Javacript syntax to check if the variable is `truthy` or `falsy`.

It's similar to saying `if (variable is true) { /* Do something */}`

In Javascript, these are `falsy` values.

1. false
2. 0 (zero)
3. "" (empty string)
4. null
5. undefined
6. NaN (Not-a-Number)

All other values are truthy, including "0" (zero as string), "false" (false as a string), empty functions, empty arrays, and empty objects.